# com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: android, kotlin, try-catch, sharedpreferences

I know there are few question for this error. I tried lots of solution but it did not work. I just want to handle if get this error. I face this problem with my phone when install apk from google play store and computer. Not getting error from build in Android Studio. My phone is Samsung Note 10 Lite Api 13.

When the face this problem, it force to clear data of app from phone. We can not ask for it from every user right. I want to handle that and clear data programmatically when this happening. But I could not do this. If we can not solve this problem yet, I want to help for this.

According to firebase crashlytics and I checked by `ToastMessage` it happenedin OnCreate of `Splash Activity`.

SplashActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity<ActivitySplashBinding>() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SplashActivityViewModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var clientPreferences: ClientPreferences

    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> ViewBinding
        get() = ActivitySplashBinding::inflate

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreateFinished() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "oncreated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[SplashActivityViewModel::class.java]
        Toast.makeText(this, "viewmodelprovider after", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

build.gradle(app)

```
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

ClientPreferences.kt

```
class ClientPreferences(context: Context) {
private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        EncryptedSharedPreferences(
            context,
            context.getString(R.string.app_name),
            masterKey,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        )
    }

    private val masterKey: MasterKey by lazy {
        MasterKey.Builder(context)
            .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
            .build()
    }
}
```

What I had tried already:

```
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

And from Manifest make false for `allowBackup` and `fullBackupContent`.
For handle crash I tried try-catch in `SplashActivity`.

```
try{
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[SplashActivityViewModel::class.java]
} catch (Exception e) {
        clientPreferences.clearSharedPreferences()
    }
```